Sale smart contract on Tact lang
I have a problem that when i send message from NftItem contract to Sale contract, value isComplete is still equals false
This is my fix price sale contract
import "@stdlib/deploy";
    import "./messages.tact";

    const minGasAmount: Int = ton("1");

    contract FixPrice with Deployable {
    isComplete: Bool = false;
    createdAt: Int as uint32;
    marketplaceAddress: Address;
    nftAddress: Address;
    nftOwnerAddress: Address;
    fullPrice: Int as coins;
    marketplaceFeeAddress: Address;
    marketplaceFee: Int as uint32;
    royaltyAddress: Address;
    royaltyAmount: Int as uint32;
    init(marketplaceAddress: Address,
    nftAddress: Address,
    nftOwnerAddress: Address,
    fullPrice: Int,
    marketplaceFeeAddress: Address,
    marketplaceFee: Int,
    royaltyAddress: Address,
    royaltyAmount: Int){
    self.createdAt = now();
    self.marketplaceAddress = marketplaceAddress;
    self.nftAddress = nftAddress;
    self.nftOwnerAddress = nftOwnerAddress;
    self.fullPrice = myBalance();
    self.marketplaceFeeAddress = marketplaceFeeAddress;
    self.marketplaceFee = marketplaceFee;
    self.royaltyAddress = royaltyAddress;
    self.royaltyAmount = royaltyAmount;
    }

    receive(msg: NftOwnershipAssigned){
    let ctx: Context = context();
    dump(ctx.value);
    dump((self.fullPrice + minGasAmount));
    require(sender() == self.nftAddress, "Invalid Owner");
    require(!(self.isComplete), "Already completed");
    nativeThrowUnless(450, ctx.value >= (self.fullPrice + minGasAmount));
    send(SendParameters{
        to: self.nftOwnerAddress,
        value: (((self.fullPrice -
          self.marketplaceFee) -
          self.royaltyAmount) +
          (myBalance() -
          ctx.value)),
        mode: SendPayGasSeparately
      }
    );
    dump("Sent message to nft owner address");
    send(SendParameters{
        to: self.royaltyAddress,
        value: self.royaltyAmount,
        mode: SendPayGasSeparately
      }
    );
    dump("Sent message to royalty address");
    send(SendParameters{
        to: self.marketplaceAddress,
        value: self.marketplaceFee,
        mode: SendPayGasSeparately
      }
    );
    dump("Sent message to marketplace address");
    send(SendParameters{
        to: self.nftAddress,
        value: 0,
        body: NftTransfer{
          query_id: msg.queryId,
          new_owner: msg.prevOwner,
          response_destination: self.nftOwnerAddress,
          custom_payload: emptyCell(),
          forward_amount: 0,
          forward_payload: beginCell().storeCoins(0).endCell().asSlice()
        }.toCell()
      }
    );
    dump("Sent message to nft address");
    dump("complete");
    self.fullPrice = (self.fullPrice - minGasAmount);
    self.isComplete = true;
    }

    get fun get_sale_data(): NftFixPriceSaleData {
    return
      NftFixPriceSaleData{
        isComplete: self.isComplete,
        createdAt: self.createdAt,
        marketplaceAddress: self.marketplaceAddress,
        nftAddress: self.nftAddress,
        nftOwnerAddress: self.nftOwnerAddress,
        fullPrice: self.fullPrice,
        marketplaceFeeAddress: self.marketplaceFeeAddress,
        marketplaceFee: self.marketplaceFee,
        royaltyAddress: self.royaltyAddress,
        royaltyAmount: self.royaltyAmount
      };
    }
    }

And this is my trait NftStandarts that NftItem implement (contract NftItem with NftStandarts)
import "../messages.tact";
//
const min_tons_for_storage: Int = ton("0.05");
//
trait NftStandarts {
  deployed: Bool;
  collection: Address;
  owner: Address;
  index: Int;
  content: Cell;

  receive(msg: NftTransfer){
    let ctx: Context = context();
    nativeThrowUnless(401, sender() == self.owner);
    require(self.deployed, "Not Deployed");
    let rest_amount: Int = (myBalance() - min_tons_for_storage);
    dump(rest_amount);
    if (msg.forward_amount != 0) {
      rest_amount = (msg.forward_amount + ctx.readForwardFee());
    }
    if (msg.response_destination != null) {
      rest_amount = (rest_amount - ctx.readForwardFee());
    }
    nativeThrowUnless(402, rest_amount >= 0);
    if (msg.forward_amount != 0) {
      send(SendParameters{
          to: msg.new_owner,
          value: msg.forward_amount,
          mode: SendPayGasSeparately,
          body: NftOwnershipAssigned{
            forwardPayload: emptySlice(),
            queryId: msg.query_id,
            prevOwner: self.owner
          }.toCell()
        }
      );
    }
    if (msg.response_destination != null) {
      send(SendParameters{
          to: msg.response_destination,
          value: rest_amount,
          body: NftExcesses{query_id: msg.query_id}.toCell()
        }
      );
    }
    self.owner = msg.new_owner;
  }

  receive(msg: NftGetStaticData){
    send(SendParameters{
        to: sender(),
        value: 0,
        mode: SendRemainingValue,
        body: NftReportStaticData{
          query_id: msg.query_id,
          index: self.index,
          collection: self.collection
        }.toCell()
      }
    );
  }

  get fun get_nft_data(): NftData {
    return
      NftData{
        deployed: self.deployed,
        index: self.index,
        collection: self.collection,
        owner: self.owner,
        content: self.content
      };
  }
}

This is my test case
await nft.send(
      deployer.getSender(),
      {
        value: toNano('5'),
      },
      {
        $$type: 'NftTransfer',
        query_id: 0n,
        new_owner: sale.address,
        response_destination: deployer.address,
        custom_payload: beginCell().endCell(),
        forward_amount: toNano('0.5'),
        forward_payload: beginCell().endCell(),
      },
    );

    console.log(await nft.getGetNftData());
    console.log(await sale.getGetSaleData());

And value isComplete from getSaleData is still equals false
What am I doing wrong?
Maybe problem with amount and value that i send in test case?
I tried to change value and amount in my test case. Looked examples on func lang, but nothing can help me. Idk what i should to do.. it breaks me.. just help.. I just want to deploy my Collection contract, deploy my nfts, deploy marketplace contract and deploy my sale contract for put on sale my nfts with fix price on TON
